# Rounded corners in a UITableView (iOS7)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, rounded-corners

In iOS7, how can I draw cell's rounded corners in a UITableView? See an example:

[image]

Comment: Chances are those cells are being custom-drawn, or they are using images. http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your `UITableview` contains `UIView`, so just use this below lines of code for making it rounded corners.
Also write this below line of code inside your tableview methods

//If iOS version < 10

For Objective-C:

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

For Swift:

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

//If iOS version >= 10

For Objective-C:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

For Swift:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Note: No need to import `QuartzCore framework` explicitly.

Comment: do you mean cell.contentView instead of view?

Comment: Don't know if using 'YES' really worked a year ago, but now at least it is 'true' not 'YES', still though, this worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using swift, I don't know, all I know is typing in YES there did not work for me, had to use true instead. I have also never heard of any code using YES or NO for BOOL until you posted that documentation page, so whatever. Think I just missed the obj-c tag even though when I found this page I was typing in swift in google.

Comment: Use ```YES``` for objective-c and ```true``` for swift.

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal is right is not working on iOS 10, but this code work.
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 13):

I subclassed UITableViewCell and had to leave out contentView to make it work.

`cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell.layer.maskToBounds = true`

Comment: I don't know why but same things works 
why cell.contentivew.layer.cornerRadius = 5; is not working ?

Comment: Did you subclass UITableViewCell? I don't develop for iOS anymore, but I thought that was the reason I originally needed this workaround.

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal `cell.contentview.layer.cornerRadius` will not be enough if the cell has a non-clear `cell.backgroundColor` or a non-clear `cell.backgroundView`. That's why hidden-username solution is probably a better solution than Hussain Shabbir or Fahim Parkar.

Answer (score 3):

Use below...

```
[cell.contentView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
[cell.contentView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

try table view delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

**Note/Recommend**: Better use Cell **XIB/NIB** file, add a **UIView** with keeping **top, bottom, left & right** corners margin via constraints, keep cell background transparent and round **UIView** corners. My solution was good at that situation. But Always go for best practices.

Comment: Your solution is even better than all the anterior ones!

Comment: Best solution ever!