# Rounded Cell with space padding in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create rounded cell with space between each one on uitableview.

like this :

[image]

as i searched in Stackoverflow there are two approch.

1: Create cell boarder with CornerRadius in cellForRowAtIndexPath like this :

```
 [cell.contentView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
 [cell.contentView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
 [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:0.5f];
 [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
```

then create footer or header per cell to get padding on each one.

2: Creating rounded uiview and then add them to cell like this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIView *whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,150)];
        whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView];
        [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedCornerView];


}
```

the downside of above approch is bad scrolling performance.

as i searched further someone suggest that i should use subclass of cell and

then reuse the cell.

this how i make my subclass :

creating "SubTableViewCell" file and add this code into it :

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIView *whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,150)];
    whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    [self.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView];
    [self.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedCornerView];
}
```

and in my main Uitableview file :

```
- (SubTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell2";
     SubTableViewCell * sctvCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
    sctvCell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
.....
....

return sctvCell;
}
```

but still it gives a bad perfomance when i scroll.

Comment: what kind of bad performance? could you please elaborate?

Comment: after scrolling in about 20 row  the scrolling goes very slowly and more than that program freezed totaly.

Comment: what you have in cell? I do what you are doing in point 2 and I never face such problems...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049226/rounded-corners-in-a-uitableview-ios7


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview

Comment: i have an imageview and few label in my cell. but still if remove them from cell still the scroll gives issue. its like when i scroll to cell it gets duplicate each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will gives bad performance as you passing static key for cell identifier which is "PlaceholderCell2":

You have to pass dynamic identifier like:

```
NSString *reuseIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%@",indexPath.row];

    SubTableViewCell * sctvCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (sctvCell == nil) {


    sctvCell= [[CellMessageDetail alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

}
```

What it will do is it will check whether for particular row id  cell is created if not then create cell or use the already created cell.

Create cell dynamically for effect:

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if(self){

       self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIView *whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,150)];
    whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    [self.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView];
    [self.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedCornerView];
    return self;

}
```

**Note :: you can put your own unique id in reuseable identifier . row id in reuseable identifier is just for reference**

Comment: thanks for answer. i tried ur code and scroll works well when i scroll to end of list . but when i scroll back the cell gets duplicate on each other and perfomance get decreased.

Comment: are you creating cell dynamically or you are using xib?

Comment: no , im using uitableviewcontroller  and subclassing the cell in another class.

Comment: Using a 'dynamic identifier' will defeat the purpose of re-usable cells and therefore always allocate a new cell, leading to increased memory usage. I can't believe that such a bad hack has been accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cells of the same size the most performant way to do this is to use a background image with cap insets as a backgroundview, setup corner layers is not really a good idea in tablesViewCells.

In this article they comment some ways to customise views with layers [article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/designing-for-ios-taming-uibutton), and in the comments here [comments](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4645585) an Apple's UIKit Engineer said that the best way memory and CPU wise is to use  resizable image background technique.

Also note that if you don't use the same identifier for all cells you can end wasting a lot of memory for long tables.